# How to get item from JSON file by key?

Tags: python, json

So I have this `JSON` file:

```
{
  "test": {
    "1.0.0": {
      "by": "xpath",
      "locator": "//div/span/a"
    },
    "1.0.1": {
      "by": "xpath1",
      "locator": "//div/span"
    },
    "1.0.2": {
      "by": "xpath2",
      "locator": "//div/span"
    }
  },
  "test1": {
    "1.0.1": {
      "by": "id",
      "locator": "add"
    },
    "1.0.2": {
      "by": "id",
      "locator": "/ADD"
    }
  },
  "test2": {
    "1.0.1": {
      "by": "css",
      "locator": "div span"
    },
    "1.0.2": {
      "by": "css",
      "locator": "div span a"
    }
  }
}
```

And I want to take 2 keys (`by` and `locator`) from the require item with name `test1` and version number `1.0.1`:

```
  "test1": {
    "1.0.1": {
      "by": "id",
      "locator": "add"
    },
```

This is what I have try:

```
with open('file.json') as f:
    json_file = load(f)
```

Get my item:

```
item = json_file.get('test1')

for x in item:
    if x == `1.0.1`_:
        print(item[x]['by'])
        print(item[x]['locator'])
```

So this works fine but I wonder how to get this in one line without this `for` loop.

Comment: You need to work through a tutorial on Python dicts.  This will teach you how to access the contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about indexing by key?

```
import json

with open('file.json') as f:
    json_file = json.load(f)

json_file["test1"]["1.0.1"]["by"]
json_file["test1"]["1.0.1"]["locator"]
```

You could wrap these calls in a `try - except KeyError` to catch if keys do not exist. Alternatively, you could explicitly check if a key exists before you use it. Something like:

```
if "1.0.1" in json_file["test1"]:
    print(json_file["test1"]["1.0.1"]["by"])
    print(json_file["test1"]["1.0.1"]["locator"])
```

You could also use `dict.get`, and if that returns `None`, then the key does not exist.

```
version_info = json_file["test1"].get("1.0.1", None)
if version_info is not None:  # exists
    print(json_file["test1"]["1.0.1"]["by"])
    print(json_file["test1"]["1.0.1"]["locator"])
```

Comment: I want to be able to know if this version exist in the file before

Comment: I mean that if i have version 1.0.2 this 1.0.1 will be good for me as well

Comment: OK so your lase example works for me but if i want to be able to specify version that not include in the file but the last version is good as well ? for example the file have 1.0.0 and 1.0.4 but the version i have is 1.0.2 so version 1.0.0 is the one that i want